# Chain lookup through queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models: `City`, and its *alias* `CityAlias`. The `CityAlias` model contains all the names in the `City`, plus the *aliases*. What I want is that whenever `City` is searched by `name`, the `CityAlias` model should be queried. This is what I've come up with:

```
class CityQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    """ If City is searched by name, search it in CityAlias """
    def _search_name_in_alias(self, args, kwargs):
        for q in args:
            if not isinstance(q, models.Q): continue
            for i, child in enumerate(q.children):
                # q.children is a list of tuples of queries:
                # [('name__iexact', 'calcutta'), ('state__icontains', 'bengal')]
                if child[0].startswith('name'):
                    q.children[i] = ('aliases__%s' % child[0], child[1])

        for filter_name in kwargs:
            if filter_name.startswith('name'):
                kwargs['aliases__%s' % filter_name] = kwargs.pop(filter_name)

    def _filter_or_exclude(self, negate, *args, **kwargs):
        # handles 'get', 'filter' and 'exclude' methods
        self._search_name_in_alias(args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        return super(CityQuerySet, self)._filter_or_exclude(negate, *args, **kwargs)


class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, related_name='cities')
    objects = CityQuerySet.as_manager()

class CityAlias(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='aliases')
```

Example: `Kolkata` will have an entry in `City` model, and it will have two entries in the `CityAlias` model: `Kolkata` and `Calcutta`. The above `QuerySet` allows to use lookups on the `name` field.
So the following two queries will return the same entry:

```
City.objects.get(name='Kolkata')     # <City: Kolkata>
City.objects.get(name__iexact='calcutta')    # <City: Kolkata>
```

So far so good. But the problem arises when `City` is a `ForeignKey` in some other model:

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    destination = models.ForeignKey(City)
    # some other fields....

Trip.objects.filter(destination__name='Kolkata').count()   # some non-zero number
Trip.objects.filter(destination__name='Calcutta').count()  # always returns zero
```

Django internally handles these joins differently, and doesn't call the `get_queryset` method of `City`'s manager. The alternative is to call the above query as following:

```
Trip.objects.filter(destination=City.objects.get(name='Calcutta'))
```

My question is that can I do something, so that however the `City` model is searched by `name`, it always searches in the `CityAlias` table instead?
Or is there another better way to implement the functionality I require?

Comment: Are you just over complicating your problem? Can you simply have Trip.destination be a foreignkey to cityalias?

Comment: The `City` model will have other fields too (like geolocation).. so it would mean using `CityAlias` when filtering by name, and `City` when other filters are applied.

Comment: Have tried this : Trip.objects.filter(destination__aliases__name='Calcutta').count()

Answer (score 4):

I think it is better (and more pythonic) to be explicit in what you ask for throughout instead of trying to do magic in the Manager and thus:

```
City.objects.get(aliases__name__iexact='calcutta') # side note: this can return many (same in original) so you need to catch that
```

And:

```
Trip.objects.filter(destination__aliases__name='Calcutta').count()
```

Comment: If the "magic" solution is possible, why not! This solution is what I was trying to avoid, but thanks I've regressed to this now..

Comment: Why not? Because it will make the code harder to understand and maintain. Keep it simple and work with your framework not twist it around. Good software is about solvning the business problems not showing off tricks.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to use [Custom Lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/howto/custom-lookups/#custom-lookups) but apparently you cannot add a table to the join list. (Well, you could add an extra({"table": ...}) in the model's manager but it's not an elegant solution).

So I'd propose you:

1) Keep always your 'main/preferred' name city also as a CityAlias. So the metadata of the city will be in City... but all the naming information will be in CityAlias. (and maybe change the names)

In this way all look-ups will happen in that table. You could have a boolean to mark which instance is the original/preferred.

```
class City(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, related_name='cities')
    [...]

class CityAlias(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='aliases')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
```

2) If you are thinking about translations... Have you thought about [django-modeltranslation](http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) app?

In this case, it would create a field for each language and it would be always better than having a join.

3) Or, if you are using PostgreSQL, and you are thinking about "different translations for the same city-name" (and I'm thinking with transliterations from Greek or Russian language), maybe you could use PostgreSQL [dictionaries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-SYNONYM-DICTIONARY), [trigrams](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgtrgm.html) with similarities, etc. Or even in this case, the 1st approach.

Comment: 1) Boolean for preferred field is kind of same (and less efficient) as having that field in the City model itself. All look-ups in the CityAlias model is what exactly want to accomplish, without anyone else worrying about the Alias table. 2) Not really looking for translations 3) will take a look at these, but not sure how they'll help..

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of keeping it simple. Why not just give the City model a char field 'CityAlias' that contains the string? If I understand your question correctly, this is the most simple solution if you only need one alias per city. It just looks to me as though you are complicating a simple problem.

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, related_name='cities')
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=255)

c = City.objects.get(alias='Kolkata')

>>>c.name
Calcutta
>>>c.alias
Kolkata
```

Comment: Except that a `City` can have multiple aliases... and I want to the queryset to return the same query set if model is searched by any of the aliases (or the original name). `City.objects.get(name=x)` should return same result if the value of `x` is Calcutta or Kolkata (or any other alias if present).

Comment: Nothing that City.CityAlias_set.all().filter(name__iexact=x) won't do?